How to position a custom time picker based on screen height in React like an HTML select element?
I have a custom time picker inside a modal for an "Add Timesheet" component, but it's not functioning as expected. I want the time picker to behave like an HTML select element in terms of positioning: if the div is taller than the window screen height, the time picker should open upwards; otherwise, it should open downwards.
Here’s the code for my custom time picker component:
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { PatternFormat } from 'react-number-format';
import moment from 'moment';
import OutsideClickHandler from '../OutsideClickHandler';

const CustomTimePicker = ({
  value, placeholder = '', isDisabled = false, onChange, onBlur,
  interval = 15, timeRef, className = ''
}) => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(value);
  const [timeslots, setTimeslots] = useState([]);
  const [isShowTimeslot, setIsShowTimeslot] = useState(false);
  const [styleValue, setStyleValue] = useState({});
  const timeslotRef = useRef(null);
  const inputDivRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeslots(generateTimeSlots());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTime(value);
  }, [value]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isShowTimeslot) calculatePosition();
    else setStyleValue({});
  }, [isShowTimeslot]);

  const calculatePosition = () => {
    const buttonRect = timeslotRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const inputRect = inputDivRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

    if (buttonRect.bottom > viewportHeight) {
      const topPosition = inputRect.top - buttonRect.height;
      setStyleValue({ top: `${topPosition}px` });
    } else {
      const bottomPosition = inputRect.bottom;
      setStyleValue({ top: `${bottomPosition}px` });
    }
  };

  const generateTimeSlots = () => {
    const times = [];
    let start = moment().startOf('day');
    const end = moment().endOf('day');
    while (start <= end) {
      times.push(start.format('HH:mm'));
      start = start.add(interval, 'minutes');
    }
    return times;
  };

  return (
    <div className={`fu-input fu-time-picker`}>
      <div ref={inputDivRef} style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
        <PatternFormat
          format={'##:##'}
          onClick={() => { setIsShowTimeslot(true); }}
          value={time}
          disabled={isDisabled}
          onValueChange={(values) => setTime(values.formattedValue)}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          placeholder={placeholder}
        />
      </div>

      {isShowTimeslot && (
        <OutsideClickHandler callback={() => setIsShowTimeslot(false)}>
          <div ref={timeslotRef} className={`timeslot`} style={styleValue}>
            {timeslots.map(timeslot => (
              <button
                key={timeslot}
                onClick={() => {
                  setIsShowTimeslot(false);
                  setTime(timeslot);
                  typeof onChange === 'function' && onChange(timeslot);
                  typeof onBlur === 'function' && onBlur();
                }}
              >
                {timeslot}
              </button>
            ))}
          </div>
        </OutsideClickHandler>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomTimePicker;

Problem:
The time picker isn't positioning itself correctly. I want it to open upwards if there's not enough space below the input field. Otherwise, it should open downwards. Right now, it doesn't behave like an HTML select element would in this scenario.

Question:
How can I adjust the positioning of this time picker so it dynamically opens upwards or downwards based on the available space, similar to an HTML select dropdown?

